# sql server when dealing with huge data using jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am facing serious issue with sql server, when I am dealing with one billion records. It is crashing production server.

```
My Approach:
===========
1.Used jtds sourceforge datasource.
2.In my code,
con.setAutoCommit(false);
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    query);
pstmt.setFetchSize(10000);
```

Somehow, sql server is ignoring fetch size hint I am specifying here and taking all the memory in server. Am i doing anything wrong here? Do we have any alternative approach to solve this? Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fetch data size vs query dataset size are different.? - you may need to edit the query for paging.

Comment: Statement fetch size only controls how many records are fetched "en block" by the jdbc driver. Its of no consequence for the actual server. If your query crashes the SQLServer, your server needs more memory or you need to restrict the query to return less records. Multiple queries for a subset are also a possibility.